# Why is an update in a trigger failing?

Tags: sql-server

There are many answers on here about how triggers should work but I wonder is mine unique in that the code runs on insert however the @type variable gets a false answer. If I run the query in isolation with the table reference I get a correct answer returned; it is only as part of the trigger that I get a false.

Part of the query calls a function but again this all works when done in isolation so I am wondering is there something else in my trigger causing it to fail that I would be unaware of?

---

SQL:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[MPH_I_TEST_GROUP_REQUEST_PRINTS]
ON [dbo].[MPH_PRINT_TEST_QUEUE]
FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS

DECLARE @V_Refno NUMERIC(10)
DECLARE @V_User_Modif VARCHAR(30)

BEGIN
SET @V_User_Modif = suser_sname()
SELECT  @V_Refno = tgreq_refno FROM inserted

--> Get details of test type
DECLARE @car_sponts VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @type VARCHAR(50)

SET @type = 'blank'
SELECT  @car_sponts = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8000),sypro.long_value)
FROM
    system_profiles sypro (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    sypro.code = 'MPH_CARD_PRT_SPONTS'
AND (sypro.archv_flag = 'N' OR sypro.archv_flag IS NULL)

--> Update type based on tests ordered
SELECT 
    @type = CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 'CARDIO' ELSE 'type fail' END --> Does the request belong in a service point noted in system profile MPH_CARD_PRT_SPONTS
FROM    
    test_group_requests tgreq (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN
    test_form_requests tfreq (NOLOCK) ON tgreq.tgreq_refno = tfreq.tgreq_refno
INNER JOIN
    test_requests tereq (NOLOCK) ON tfreq.tfreq_refno = tereq.tfreq_refno
INNER JOIN
    test_definitions tstdf (NOLOCK) ON tereq.tstdf_refno = tstdf.tstdf_refno
INNER JOIN
    test_locations tstlc (NOLOCK) ON tstlc.tstdf_refno = tstdf.tstdf_refno
WHERE   
    tgreq.tgreq_refno IN (SELECT tgreq_refno FROM inserted)
AND (tstlc.archv_flag = 'N' OR tstlc.archv_flag IS NULL)
AND tstlc.spont_refno IN
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT spont.spont_refno FROM service_points spont (NOLOCK) WHERE (spont.archv_flag = 'N' OR spont.archv_flag IS NULL) AND spont.code IN (SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[MPH_PARSELIST](@car_sponts))
    )

--> Update test type to print queue
UPDATE  mph_print_test_queue
SET mph_print_test_queue.type = 'updated ' + @type
FROM
    inserted,mph_print_test_queue
WHERE
    mph_print_test_queue.tgreq_refno = inserted.tgreq_refno

END
```

So currently all records get a type of 'updated type fail' even when they meet the criteria for 'cardio' to be inserted/updated.

Thanks in advance.
Phil.

---

Tried this update also:

```
UPDATE  mph_print_test_queue
SET mph_print_test_queue.type = 'updated cardio'
FROM    
    inserted,test_group_requests tgreq (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN
    test_form_requests tfreq (NOLOCK) ON tgreq.tgreq_refno = tfreq.tgreq_refno
INNER JOIN
    test_requests tereq (NOLOCK) ON tfreq.tfreq_refno = tereq.tfreq_refno
INNER JOIN
    test_definitions tstdf (NOLOCK) ON tereq.tstdf_refno = tstdf.tstdf_refno
INNER JOIN
    test_locations tstlc (NOLOCK) ON tstlc.tstdf_refno = tstdf.tstdf_refno
WHERE   
    tgreq.tgreq_refno = inserted.tgreq_refno
AND (tstlc.archv_flag = 'N' OR tstlc.archv_flag IS NULL)
AND tstlc.spont_refno IN
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT spont.spont_refno FROM service_points spont (NOLOCK) WHERE (spont.archv_flag = 'N' OR spont.archv_flag IS NULL) AND spont.code IN (SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[MPH_PARSELIST](@car_sponts))
    )
```

Comment: Problem number one is right here: "SELECT  V_Refno = tgreq_refno FROM inserted". The inserted collection can contain multiple rows... but this trigger is assuming only one row. ALL triggers should ALWAYS assume inserted/deleted can have multiple rows, and work on SETS, not scalars. On an update, V_Refno will only contain the value of the last row in inserted, for example, if multiple rows were updated.

Comment: @pmbAustin  
Thanks, I have tried a million variations of that update knowing the issue is somewhere in there and still no joy. A batch update I tried earlier does not work either so what is the magic touch? I added the update to the end of the main thread.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this before you continue splattering nolock hints all over the place. It is far more sinister than many people realize. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ And in your update you really should use ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around for 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for the tips. I'm in that bad habit because the application using this DB is forever locking up and we are not allowed to change global settings to compensate. Still; it is a bad habit I should put more thought in to. Regarding the joins the query is not finished but was changed about a million times today due to my own mental block on the issue. Thanks again for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the light bulb moment on my way home. Don't link the update to inserted table but just batch update according to matching records.

Sorry for not getting this before posting. Long day.